# How to properly initialize a variable in python

Tags: python, styles, instantiation

I tried searching this up before asking it here, but from what I have searched it does not seem to be asked in the form that I am thinking.

For a simple example, imagine a situation where I have a list of integers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and I want to iterate through the list and save the largest number that is divisible by 2. *(And yes, if the list was not ordered this code wouldn't work, but for the sake of example imagine all the lists are in numbered order)*

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for number in nums:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        max_num = number

print(str(max_num))
```

In this example, I would be able to print max_num without issue. However, if the list nums was [1, 3, 5] for example, max_num would never be set, and I would be referencing a variable I never instantiated.

**My question is how would I properly set the variable prior to the loop? To state it otherwise, would you ever need to describe the data type of a variable prior to setting it, akin to Java and C++? Is it even necessary?**

What I have been doing recently is something like this:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
max_num = None      # <- added this

for number in nums:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        max_num = number

if max_num is not None:     # <- added if statement
    print(str(max_num))
```

But I feel like there would be a better way of doing it. I also had the idea to try this:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
max_num = int          # <- this was changed

for number in nums:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        max_num = number

print(str(max_num))
```

The issue with this way it it makes max_num type(int), which I don't believe is correct either.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am not specifically looking for a solution to the example I have, but instead a pythonic way of setting a variable.

Comment: Your two solutions are equally good for the purposes they serve. They may be other solutions available to you. I think you need to think what each case means to you: 1. There is a `max_num` and you can print it. 2. There is no number available to print.

Comment: `max(number for number in nums if number % 2 == 0)` would throw a `ValueError` in the absence of even numbers, unless you added a value as the `default` keyword argument.

Comment: I get the impression the OP isn't specifically looking for a "max even number" solution (if so, stepping through the list backwards would be more efficient) but is rather looking for a Pythonic manner to detect whether the desired result was found.

Comment: Do not do `max_num = int`. That is not a declaration even if it looks like one. It makes `max_num` a synonym of `int`, so that `max_num(math.pi)` will return `3`. That sort of thing will come back to bite you. Do `max_num = None` as you have been doing.

Comment: @sj95126 is correct, I am not looking for an answer to the specific example I put in the question, the example was simply to help me get my point across with finding a pythonic way to see if a variable was ever set prior to being accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example exactly does what you need. It does assign a default value `None` to `max_num`.

You don't need to specifically check if `max_num` is not `None`. If at all the list contains any value that is divisible by 2, it will be assigned to `max_num`. If not, `max_num` will be `None` ( the default value) which means - *No number divisible by 2 exists in the list.*

```
nums = [1, 3, 5]
max_num = None      # <- added this

for number in nums:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        max_num = number

print(max_num)
```

The above code, if

```
nums = [1, 3, 4, 5] - Returns 4 -> Max. number divisible by 2 exists
```

```
nums = [1,3,5] - Returns None -> No number divisible by 2 exists.
```

Comment: Say I need to use the number in a function ( do_sth(max_num) ). In this case, max_num needs to be an integer, and not None. would the best way to do this be a simple if not None: statement?

Comment: You can also look into type hinting in python.

Comment: @Zev that fits really well with my issue, I believe this answers my problem.